# Delete `,` prettier/prettier and Parse errors in imported module './routes'

Tags: reactjs, parsing, token, prettier

I download a MUI template for a React web-base app.
In Routes.js file, I commented out a line
and deleted the "," before this line. Later I uncomment the line and add the ",", so it looks the same as before; however, there is an issue as follows: when npm start, it fails to compile.

I'm beginner for reactjs and can't understand what this means.

```
src\App.js
  Line 2:20:  Parse errors in imported module './routes': Unexpected token, expected "," (26:8) (26:8)  import/no-named-as-default
  Line 2:20:  Parse errors in imported module './routes': Unexpected token, expected "," (26:8) (26:8)  import/no-named-as-default-member

src\routes.js
  Line 24:52:  Delete `,`  prettier/prettier
  Line 36:55:  Delete `,`  prettier/prettier

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

routes.js is as follows:

```
import { Navigate, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
// layouts
import DashboardLayout from './layouts/dashboard';
import LogoOnlyLayout from './layouts/LogoOnlyLayout';
//
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import DashboardApp from './pages/DashboardApp';
import Products from './pages/Products';
import Blog from './pages/Blog';
import User from './pages/User';
import NotFound from './pages/Page404';
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

export default function Router() {
  return useRoutes([
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      element: <DashboardLayout />,
      children: [
        { element: <Navigate to="/dashboard/app" replace /> },
        { path: 'app', element: <DashboardApp /> },
        { path: 'user', element: <User /> },
        { path: 'products', element: <Products /> },
        // { path: 'blog', element: <Blog /> },
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <LogoOnlyLayout />,
      children: [
        { path: 'login', element: <Login /> },
        { path: 'register', element: <Register /> },
        { path: '404', element: <NotFound /> },
        { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> },
        { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> },
      ]
    },
    { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" replace /> }
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this question by adding two lines in .eslintrc file

```
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default-member": 0,
```

that means, I unactive that two rules so no compliling error will be caused by these two rules